# Create a function that accepts a generic function parameter, call it with a Type, and get the transformed return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'd like to create a function that

1. takes in a function as a generic parameter that transforms type from `X->Y`
2. "calls" the function and returns the type that is the result of applying given transformation to a specific type (i.e. Y given an X)

Namely, something like

```
type Foo<Transformer extends <X>(x: X) => any> = ReturnType<Transformer<{bar: string}>>
```

Which could then be used like such

```
type X = Foo<<X>(val: X) => X & { foo: string }>;
// X = { bar: string } & { foo: string }
```

This attempt fails at return type of `foo` with `Type 'Transformer' is not generic`. Is there any way to achieve this some other way?

Comment: Not really. Higher kinded types aren't implemented in TypeScript yet.

Comment: @jcalz this is purely type-level gymnastics, so actual concrete implementation doesn't matter in this case. In this case avoiding the need to pass a concrete implementation is actually the whole point

Answer (score 0):

So there is a hack to achieve this.

First you need to create an interface:

```js
interface Lambda {
  input: unknown
  output: unknown
}
```

Now you have an interface where two keys are known and you could reference them.
So now you can create an type that holds a generic like this:

```
interface Uppercase extends Lambda {
 output:UpperCase<this["input"] & string> //<-- reference the unknown input 
}
```

Now create a small helper that calls your Uppercase hkt

```
type Call<L extends Lambda, Arg> = L & {input:Arg}
```

Unknown is just a placeholder in TypeScript by intersecting it with any other type unknown will get overwritten but the reference will be still there. Note: Omit won't work! Internally Typescript will generate a new object and the reference will break!

Now you can call the uppercase hkt without providing a generic directly

```
type Test = Call<Uppercase, "hello"> //HELLO
```

I hope this helps you a little bit.